# Add live-reload plugin in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) to get a live-reload whenever there is a change in one of the files. The way I get a live-reload/server on, is I open cmd and locate the current project folder. I then type in `live-server` and click enter. A browser opens up with a `live-server`

I want to avoid opening cmd, and just add an item in the menu in sublime text saying `live-server`. When I click on it, I want it to open a browser with live-reload. How can I achieve that?

(I did do my research before, and I didn't find a clear tutorial of doing 'outside' things in sublime text. Meaning, I can do some text insertions, or highlighting, but I didn't find any tutorial with some advanced stuff.)

Comment: If you're currently using a Sublime Text plugin you trigger from the command palette – what's the name of the plugin? I only know of [LiveReload](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload) but that has nothing to do with live-server. Creating [menus](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/menus.html) in Sublime Text is trivial, but we need to know the command you're trying to trigger.

Comment: @idleberg I want the command to open a browser and it should reload anytime a file gets saved in that directory.
With the `liveReload` plugin, you have to add some JavaScript and I don't even know what to insert in the parameters. I want a plugin, (prefer to create one, or create it off an existing one, like the one you posted,) and add a menu of live reload.
Thanks!